# Get & Set actual object type with Object.GetType() possible?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a function that returns the actual control. I know you can do this when you know the type of the object:

```
public static Control GetCtl(this object obj)
{
    //(obj as obj.GetType()) ?
    return (TextBox)obj;
}
```

But what if I need to get one from some other (unknown) object type, for example TextBox or RichTextBox? I will then use that on:

```
private void TextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sender.GetCtl().Select(0, 0);
}
```

Though `TextBox` and `RichTextBox` seem to have the same `Select` method, when I tried the above `GetCtl()` function, it always threw an error. How do I do this properly?

**Edit**:
Since you cannot access the "complete" control property as `sender` in all native procedures/methods (i.e `_Click()`, `_MouseMove()`) I want to make a function that can return the actual control, not sure how to explain this better, but here's how I would use it:

```
Private void SomeControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    sender.getCtl().   //<-- so I can access anything here

    (sender as Button).Text = "sometext"  // <-- so I won't have to do this

    //I wish the following would work. But you get the idea
    (sender.GetType())sender.Text = "";
    //or...
    (sender as sender.GetType()).Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RichTextBox` and `TextBox` are both derived from [TextBoxBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.aspx).

To tell the compiler that you want to treat an object as a specific type, you can perform a **cast** operation. In this case, you need to cast `sender` to `TextBoxBase` and then you can access the [Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s.aspx) method:

```
private void TextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = sender as TextBoxBase;
    if (textbox != null)
        textbox.Select(0, 0);
}
```

This uses the [as keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) to cast the `sender` object to `TextBoxBase`. Note that you can't simply cast anything to anything else. The object being cast must actually be an instance of the type you're casting to. If `sender` is not an instance of something derived from `TextBoxBase`, the cast operation will return null.

Generally winforms event handlers should only be raised in very controlled and known circumstances - you should be very confident that this event is being raised by a control derived from TextBoxBase. There's not much point in raising it from anything else.

If you really want a method to convert sender to a TextBoxBase, you could write it as:

```
private TextBoxBase ToTextBoxBase(object sender)
{
    var textbox = sender as TextBoxBase;
    if (textbox == null)
        throw new Exception("The given object is not derived from TextBoxBase");

    return textbox;
}
```

You would use it like:

```
ToTextBoxBase(sender).Select(0, 0);
```

If the sender is not a TextBoxBase, this call would throw the "The given object is not derived from TextBoxBase" exception.

The important point to understand is that you are working with a strongly typed language. If you attempt to call a method of an object which is not of a type containing that method, the program won't even compile (unless the type is `dynamic`, but that's another discussion).

It is possible to create a method that you can call with this syntax:

```
sender.ToTextBoxBase()
```

This is called an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). However, you would be extending the `System.Object` class for a very specific purpose, which is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks! That actually does it, but can you help me with constructing the custom method `getCtl()`? Because I want to also use it on **other controls** to easily access the methods of `sender`.

Comment: I mean can you still access the object/control's method when the cast operation returns `null`? Which means it's not `TextBoxBase` but something else

Comment: @jom: until you case sender to something, the only methods you can access are the methods of the System.Object class, which aren't very useful. The idea of a method which converts sender to a TextBoxBase is possible, but not very useful. I'll edit my answer to give you an example though.

Comment: I also edited my question a bit and thanks for your detailed explanations, I learned something new again today.

Comment: I will do it without extension method too and just do it like in your example (`ToTextBoxBase(sender)._`) no problem, my point is, I just want to get the actual object of `sender` as the output to access its methods from.